# Extract specific features from SharePoint

Tags: document-library, migration

Currently working on a SharePoint 2010 project, I'm evaluating what needs to be done to extract our specific code from SharePoint.

The idea is to extract the specific features we added in SharePoint to put them outside of SharePoint.

At first sight, I suppose we need to think of how we are going to interface with SharePoint to manage the document libraries for example.

Is there any website or document or do you have any advice to do that? I did my homework but didn't find anything convincing for now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish or what information you are looking for. Can you reword the question or provide some additional information?

Comment: I completed the answer, is it better now?

Comment: I think - you want to find all features you've added to SharePoint and then extract those features to a location outside of SharePoint? Do you have any programming requirements? For example, do you want to do it with PowerShell only or is any solution acceptable?

Comment: The specific code we currently have in SharePoint is based on ASP .NET Web Forms. I would like to extract it from SharePoint to use it in a external website. Because there are some SharePoint features, like the document library, I suppose we'll have some difficulties to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Give these PowerShell scripts a try as a starting point:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/10/08/powershell-script-find-all-sharepoint-features-installed-on-farm.aspx

Version 1

```
$url = "Your site URL here"

$site= new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)

$site.WebApplication.Farm.FeatureDefinitions `
| where-object {$_.solutionid -ne '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'} `
| Sort-Object solutionid,displayname `
| ft -property solutionid,displayname,scope -auto > features.txt

$site.Dispose()
```

Version 2

```
$url = "Your site URL here"

$site= new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)

#send all features to output file features.txt
$site.WebApplication.Farm.FeatureDefinitions `
| where-object {$_.solutionid -ne '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'} `
| Sort-Object solutionid,displayname `
| ft -property displayname,scope -auto -groupBy solutionid > features.txt

#replace solutionId in features.txt with solution name
foreach($s in $site.WebApplication.Farm.Solutions)
{
    (Get-Content features.txt) `
    | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $s.solutionid.ToString(), $s.Name} `
    | Set-Content features.txt    
}

$site.Dispose()
```

You the should be able to use the `SPFeatureDefinition Class` to either get the Feature Folder and Files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition(v=office.14).aspx

Here is an example of someone deleting feature files. It may serve as a good reference for you to copy the files:

http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2012/01/sp2010-feature-files-cleanup-extension.html

I've copied their code here for reference in case the page is unavailable.

```
namespace Puzzlepart.SharePoint.Core.SPExtentions
{
    public static class SPFeatureDefinitionExtentions
    {
        public class Module
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public List<string> Files { get; set; }
        }


        public static void DeleteFeatureFiles
(this SPFeatureDefinition spFeatureDefinition, string moduleName, SPWeb web)
        {
            List<Module> modules = GetModuleFiles(spFeatureDefinition, moduleName);
            foreach (Module module in modules)
            {
                DeleteModuleFiles(module, web);
            }
        }


        public static void DeleteFeatureWebPartFiles
(this SPFeatureDefinition spFeatureDefinition, SPWeb web)
        {
            List<Module> modules = GetAllModuleFiles(spFeatureDefinition);
            foreach (Module module in modules)
            {
                if (string.Compare(module.Path, "_catalogs/wp", 
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                    DeleteModuleFiles(module, web);
            }
        }


        private static List<Module> GetModuleFiles
(SPFeatureDefinition spFeatureDefinition, string moduleName)
        {
            string elementsPath = string.Format(@"{0}\FEATURES\{1}\{2}\Elements.xml", 
SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("Template"), 
spFeatureDefinition.DisplayName, moduleName);
            XDocument elementsXml = XDocument.Load(elementsPath);
            XNamespace sharePointNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/";

            // get each module name and the files in it
            var moduleList =
                from module in elementsXml.Root.Elements(sharePointNamespace + "Module")
                select new
                {
                    Name = (module.Attributes("Name").Any()) 
? module.Attribute("Name").Value : null,
                    ModuleUrl = (module.Attributes("Url").Any()) 
? module.Attribute("Url").Value : null,
                    Files = module.Elements(sharePointNamespace + "File")
                };

            List<Module> modules = new List<Module>();
            // iterate through each module with files
            foreach (var module in moduleList)
            {
                Module m = new Module()
                               {
                                   Name = module.Name,
                                   Path = module.ModuleUrl
                               };
                List<string> files = new List<string>();
                foreach (var fileElement in module.Files)
                {
                    string filename = (fileElement.Attributes("Name").Any()) 
? fileElement.Attribute("Name").Value : fileElement.Attribute("Url").Value;
                    files.Add(filename);
                }
                m.Files = files;
                modules.Add(m);
            }
            return modules;
        }

        private static void DeleteModuleFiles(Module module, SPWeb web)
        {
            foreach (string filename in module.Files)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(module.Path))
                    web.GetFile(string.Format("{0}/{1}", module.Path, filename)).Delete();
                else
                    web.Files.Delete(filename);
            }
        }

        private static List<Module> GetAllModuleFiles
(SPFeatureDefinition spFeatureDefinition)
        {
            var moduleList = new List<Module>();

            string modulesPath = string.Format(@"{0}\FEATURES\{1}\", 
SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("Template"), 
spFeatureDefinition.DisplayName);
            DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(modulesPath);
            foreach (DirectoryInfo moduleFolder in folder.GetDirectories())
            {
                moduleList.AddRange(GetModuleFiles(spFeatureDefinition, moduleFolder.Name));
            }

            return moduleList;
        }

    }
}
```